# find items from current position containing specific nodes

Tags: xslt

I need to parse an xml consisting of components inside nested groups. The result will be js array. I want the group to be created only if has a component in its nested levels.
I can search if a node has components with below method:

```
<xsl:if test="count(.//ModuleComponent) > 0">
```

and I need to put comma between the array elements only if the other all nodes from current position has components. And this is what I can't do. I need to search if inside all nodes from current if they have components.

this line works only in the next sibling, not all of them.

```
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::ModuleComponent) > 0">
```

my sample is:

```
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<!--create components of group-->
<xsl:for-each select="Module/Groups/Group">
    <xsl:call-template name="GroupTemplate">
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>


<xsl:template name="GroupTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="groupID" select="@ID"/>
    <!-- create this group only if it has components deep inside -->
    <xsl:if test="count(.//ModuleComponent) > 0">
        {
            id: <xsl:value-of select="$ID" />
            ...
            group body
            ...
        }
        <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::ModuleComponent) > 0"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and sample xml is:

```
<Module>
    <Groups>
        <Group ID="1">
            <Groups>
                <Group ID="11">
                    <Component ID="c1"/>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
        </Group>
        <Group ID="2">
            <Groups>
                <Group ID="22">
                </Group>
            </Groups>
        </Group>
        <Group ID="3">
            <Groups>
                <Group ID="33">
                    <Component ID="c3"/>
                </Group>
            </Groups>
        </Group>
    </Groups>
</Module>
```

any ideas or help is appreciated.

Comment: In your source there is no `ModuleComponent`. There is no `$ID` and your XSLT file is not complete. Please correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a matching template instead of a called one, and move the "do I contain any `ModuleComponent`" logic into a predicate instead of an `if`:

```
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Module/Groups/Group[.//ModuleComponent]"/>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>

<xsl:template match="Group">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
  {
        id: <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        ...
        group body
        ...
  }
</xsl:template>
```

Now you're operating only on the groups that have at least one component, and `position()` is the position of this `Group` within *that list* rather than within the list of *all* groups, so you simply add a comma before all but the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an array, you don't have to call a separate template. You could change your first `for-each` to iterate on `.//Component` and test for the `last()` position:

```
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select=".//Component">
    {
    id: <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
    ...
    component body
    ...
    }
    <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've made a mistake in above post. 
updated this:
 ...
    component body
    ...
to this:
 ...
    group body
    ...
 
it's just creating groups. not components. groups are nested. and only the ones that have components is created. another template is used inside group to create components.